# Log in to Sharepoint 2016 using your Enterprise Office 365 account

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-365, authentication, 2016

I want to create a Sharepoint 2016 site. For this I will first install Sharepoint 2016 on a VM. I would like users to log into the Sharepoint 2016 site using their Office 365 credentials so that I do not have do any kind of Identity Mangement. Is this possible in SP2016 ? Need help?

NOTE: My Sharepoint 2016 is a on premise installation on a single VM (single farm install). I want my fellow employees to use our organizational office 365 account to sign-in to my sharepoint site. I am newbie to Sharepoint. So it would be nice if you could outline the steps and point me to any documentation for details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve what I wanted to using [auth0's Sharepoint Integration feature](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/sharepoint). In order to connect with organizational O365 account, I had create a [auth0 enterprise connection with Azure AD](https://manage.auth0.com/#/connections/enterprise) My sharepoint site does not need to know anything more than the user's email address and hence I do not need to read any private info from AD. If more info needs to be read from AD then one would require permission from administrator who manages the org's O365 accounts.

Answer (score 3):

First of all,

SharePoint Online works with the login name using UPN (**user principle name**) which is in most cases it will the user's email ID. so if your login ID is same as UPN (Microsoft's recommendation for Office 365 Identities) then you can use the same login name (i.e, Email ID and earlier it used to be firstname_lastname, Employee ID etc.. as per your organization infrastructure best practices) to login in to SharePoint 2016 as well.

**Note:**

You need to update and maintain the UPN before setting up the Office 365 tenant for your organization as part of pre-configuration process. You can refer the below articles but you may google more as well

[Reference Link-1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Prepare-to-provision-users-through-directory-synchronization-to-Office-365-01920974-9e6f-4331-a370-13aea4e82b3e)

[Reference Link-2](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2015/07/office-365-why-your-upn-should-match-your-primary-smtp-address/)

I personally tested this in 2010 and 2013 as well and i dont see any problems while login in to the on-premises versions of SharePoint.

Also, I assume you might have already planned for Directory Sync for Office 365 which will enforce and maintain the policies, credentials both in cloud and on-premises Active Directory as identical.

Comment: What you've described is a work around, but I don't think accurately answers the question. The question boils down to 'can you use an Azure AD identity to log into on-prem SharePoint'. Obviously if you're simply using a UPN, you're just leveraging AD and not Azure AD...

Comment: @TrevorSeward not really. thats the best articulated answer for the question. the question doesnt talk about any Azure AD or something else. the main point of the question is how to use same O365 credentails with out additional effort and more over it's not a work around and its a must for Office 365.

Comment: You should understand that Azure AD is the source objects for O365; AAD Connect does not go AD -> O365 directly, rather O365 leverages Azure AD. In addition, it is possible to have Azure AD only objects (B2B, B2C, "cloud only"), which in your scenario will not function on-prem. For a scenario like this, we'd need to look into, for example, Azure ACS.

Comment: @TrevorSeward not sure if you have read my answer clearly. i also mentioned about the directory sync which means the login credentails from on-premises AD will be replicated to Azure AD can be used even to login in to office 365 with or without federation-ADFS. so the same login credentails applies to either on-premises Sharepoint servers or Office 365. and also, i am totally aware of cloud only accounts.

Comment: I read your answer, but I think you're misunderstanding the concept based on the original posters current wording of using Azure AD (aka O365) credentials on-prem. This does not involve Active Directory, nor should it be conflated with Active Directory.

Comment: @kesava I added a note to my question if that clarifies things. I am afraid I am kind of confused now.  Could you please respond to the note.